# Use cURL to log in HTTPS site from my site

Tags: php, curl, https

I tried to use the following code to login a website. It has a popup message

"Although this page is encrypted, the information you have entered is to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could easily be read by a third party. Are you sure you want to continue sending this information?"

the "Continue" button needs to be clicked before the access is granted.

The code doesn't work, I am not sure if it has anything to do with the message or what else I didn't do right?

```
$url = "https://anothersite.com/login.php";
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/A.B (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/X.Y.Z.W Safari/A.B.";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "1234";
$postfields = "username=".$username."&password=".$password;
$cookie_file_path = getcwd().'/cookie.txt';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

echo curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are not using a certificate issued by an authorized CA.

Try setting below to false. it should work.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` The value setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER should be a bool: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: The first call was right (it should be an integer) so it would be `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);`

Comment: I tried the changes but it only echoed out the login page asking for username and password.